# Cannot upload deployment on WildFly 10

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly-10

I am new on using WildFly 10. When I tried to deploy a WAR on WildFly 10, I got the following error:

> Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerservice.war\".PARSE" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerservice.war\".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153:
>   Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"customerservice.war\"
>   Caused by:
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
>   WFLYUT0027: Failed to parse XML descriptor
>   \"/content/customerservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/taglibs-application.jar\"
>   at [1,0] Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF
>   in prolog at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]"}}

Comment: Could you please update your question with the contents of your WAR's *web.xml*?

Comment: yes i when i tries to upload a war using gui then i got this message also using cli

Comment: 10:29:29,876 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.default: Could not start http listener
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:142)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at or

Comment: Ok... But can you provide your *web.xml*?